# Dynamically add form fields in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

So I'm building a quiz app where people can create quizzes and I'd like to get a better understanding of how meteor can handle dynamic forms. The quiz will be something like 'Which Star Wars Character are you?'

Then the user would fill in 'descriptive nouns' like Chewbacca, R2D2, etc. in order to create the quiz. However I'd like the the user to be able to choose how many descriptive nouns by clicking an add button to add more choices. I could probably figure out how to change the name attribute such as 'descriptive-noun2', 'descriptive-noun3' on the HTML side of things, but I can't figure out how to do this for the submit event. These will also have an image associated with them. Is there a way I can submit this as an array, or how else could I be able to dynamically submit these to the database? Thank you!

HTML:

```
    <div class="control-group noun">            
        <label class="control-label" for="descriptive-noun"></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="descriptive-noun" type="text" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group noun">            
        <label class="control-label" for="descriptive-noun"></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="descriptive-noun" type="text" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.quizSubmit.events({ 
'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var quiz = {      
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
      descriptive_noun1: $(e.target).find('[name=descriptive-noun').val(),
      descriptive_noun2: $(e.target).find('[name=descriptive-noun').val()
    }

    quiz._id = Quizzes.insert(quiz);
    Router.go('quizItemDetails', quiz);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is really a question about HTML forms.

First, your HTML needs to have a `<form>` element in it. That form will contain the `<input>` fields that you create.  As you suggest, you can add new `<input>` elements to the  dynamically.

```
<form id='form'>
  <input name="descriptive-noun1" type="text" value=""/>
  <input name="descriptive-noun2" type="text" value=""/>
  <input name="descriptive-noun3" type="text" value=""/>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Then, on the JavaScript side, you get the data inside the  like this

```
Template.quizSubmit.events({
  'submit' : function(event) {
     var formData = $('#form').serializeArray()
     event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

The variable `formData` will have an array of objects containing the name and value of each  element. You can then insert them into a database.

Comment: I actually did have the form element, just forgot to include it. Thanks, this a great answer.